# падения при CoUninitialize()

Tags: c++, windows, dll, отладка, com

Есть приложение под WIN состоящее из множества dll. Для работы этого приложения необходим DCOM. Иногда и не очень стабильно происходят исключения после последнего вызова CoUninitialize(). Исключение это не правильный доступ к памяти(0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000035BF2B60.). На сколько я понимаю происходит вызов метода Release объекта выгруженного из памяти если смотреть дамп созданный при исключении(combase.dll!CStdMarshal::DisconnectSrvIPIDs(unsigned long dwType) Line 4938    C++). Проблема в том как понять кто не уничтожив объект выгрузился. Не от всех dll есть исходный код. Может как-то можно узнать GUID этого не разрушенного объекта или имя длл которая не его создала и не освободила?

Comment: Убедитесь, что при вызове CoUninitialize в программе нет не осталось ни одного живого объекта и / или фонового потока.

Comment: В windows всё строется на куче. Куча общая, поэтому не получится узнать кто не инициализировался. По идее можна через ToolHelp обойти кучу (надо её ещё найти). Но это другой вопрос тогда. А зачем вам делать  CoUninitialize? Вам нужно завершить работу программы? Поставьте его в try-catch. Или завешитесь принудительно через TerminateProcess - я так делал что бы исправить проблему с COM-программой для кассы (что бы не нажимать 20 раз ок на сообщениях об ошибке при выходе).

Comment: @nick_n_a *"Или завешитесь принудительно через TerminateProcess - я так делал что бы исправить проблему с COM-программой для кассы (что бы не нажимать 20 раз ок на сообщениях об ошибке при выходе)."* - в машине индикатор неисправности тормозной системы наверное тоже заклеиваете, чтобы не мешал?

Answer (score 2):

В момент вызова `CoUninitialize` все созданные COM-объекты должны быть уничтожены. У вас кто-то остается жить и уничтожается уже после уничтожения подсистемы COM. Отсюда и ошибка

Как искать: не вызывать `CoUninitialize`, а поставить точку останова на `combase.dll!CStdMarshal::DisconnectSrvIPIDs`. Когда она сработает, посмотреть стек вызовов и попытаться угадать какой объект уничтожается

Comment: Да всё верно говорите. Но повторяемость крайне редкая раз в неделю может быть. И есть только дампы исисключением и стеком вызова. Вот куда там смотреть в этот стек ? call        ObjectMethodExceptionHandlingAction<<lambda_2a3a7b5175b0a5e47c77e1d8eff078e5> > (07FFAD006B1C4h)  где то наверное можно найти адрес в этом стеке. но dll уже на верняка выгружены из памяти и по тем адресам мусор. Возможно можно попробовать не выгружать dll га время тестов. Попробую спасибо за совет.

Comment: @НиколайСтаровойтов Логируйте адреса, по которым загружены dll. Еще вариант - в момент предполагаемого вызова CoUnitiliize зафиксируйте все загруженный в данный момент dll с их адресами загрузки